# Testing attaching a file with Dusk - works via Tinker but not from the Test

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I have a file uploader for which I have written the following test:

```
$browser->visit('/product/professional-photo-prints')
        ->attach('photo', __DIR__.'/storage/app/public/testing/test_upload.jpg');
```

That doesn't upload the file. No error either.

However, when I do this:

```
$browser->visit('/product/professional-photo-prints')
        ->tinker();
```

and once in the Terminal launched by Tinker, when I enter the exact same file uploading command I am using in the test:

```
$browser->attach('photo', __DIR__.'/storage/app/public/testing/test_upload.jpg');
```

...it works. I can see my Chrome instance upload the file and all.

I can't figure out for the life of me what could be the difference between that command being run from the test itself, or from Tinker.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

P.S. I am using Laravel 5.5 and Dusk 2.0

Comment: Thanks for this question. I had never heard of using `$browser->tinker();` in Dusk. I just found this, which was also interesting: https://tighten.co/blog/supercharge-your-laravel-tinker-workflow I'm still not quite sure whether it could help me. I'm on Win 10 using Homestead and would rather be able to slowly watch in a GUI what the test is actually doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**DIR** magic constant refers to the parent folder of the file being executed.

```
->attach('photo', __DIR__.'/storage/app/public/testing/test_upload.jpg');
```

Of course there is no file found by this path. You should try this instead:

```
->attach('photo', storage_path('app/public/testing/test_upload.jpg'));
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. (how come when in Tinker, the DIR magic constant worked?)

Comment: It worked from tinker because you were acting as a browser. 

`$browser->attach('photo', __DIR__.'/storage/app/public/testing/test_upload.jpg');`

In this case the entry point for your request was index.php in public directory. Assume this file was executed and the path was: public/storage/app/public/testing/test_upload.jpg. That's why it worked.

Comment: Understood. Thank you once again Sergei!

Comment: The question is why does laravel doc about Dusk is using __DIR__ for attaching files?

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if your test file is inside your public (for example), you can use `base_path`;

e.g: `base_path("public/sample-recording/test.mp3")`